# How to call java methods in testng class

Tags: java, report, testng

I am getting error in testng report:

I followed the below steps

1. I wrote all my testcases in java methods and used java verifications like if else to pass my testcases

2.I created one testng class, in the testng class i called my all java methods

1. I executed the testng class this class contain around 30 java methods, each and every method is one testcase.
2. If i execute that class reports generated for testng based annotations, it does not consider the java methods into testcases, how can i call my all java methods? i need to generate reports for my java methods

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DocumentSearchTest {
    WebElements webEleObj;
    /*
     * AllLetter Lettobj ; AllSearch allseObj; AllTranscript TraObj;
     */
    FrameSearchExported fseObj;
    TextBoxSearch textObj;
    DateSinceSearch dateSinceObj;

    /*
     * public void loginTest() throws FileNotFoundException, BiffException,
     * IOException, InterruptedException {
     * webEleObj.textbox(webEleObj.properties
     * ("Username"),webEleObj.excelRead(1,2,1));
     * webEleObj.textbox(webEleObj.properties
     * ("Password"),webEleObj.excelRead(2,2,1)); webEleObj.sleep(5000);
     * webEleObj.button(webEleObj.properties("Login")); webEleObj.sleep(20000);
     * 
     * }
     */

    @BeforeClass
    public void start() throws FileNotFoundException, BiffException,
    IOException, InterruptedException, RowsExceededException,
    WriteException {
        // Assert.assertEquals(true, true, "Loggend into application");
        webEleObj = new WebElements();
        /*
         * allseObj = new AllSearch(webEleObj); Lettobj = new
         * AllLetter(webEleObj); TraObj =new AllTranscript(webEleObj);
         */
        fseObj = new FrameSearchExported(webEleObj);
        textObj = new TextBoxSearch(webEleObj);
        dateSinceObj = new DateSinceSearch(webEleObj);
        webEleObj.browserLaunch();
        webEleObj.loginTest();
        webEleObj.sleep(20000);
        webEleObj.setUpApp();
        // webEleObj.excelwrite(4);
        System.out.println("hi logged in");
    }

    @Test
    public void ts_1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
    InterruptedException, RowsExceededException, BiffException,
    WriteException {
        webEleObj.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("First TestCase---->");
        fseObj.allexportedSearch();
        fseObj.letterexportedSearch();
        fseObj.transcriptexportedSearch();
        fseObj.allnotexpSearch();
        fseObj.letternotexpSearch();
        fseObj.transcriptnotexpSearch();
        fseObj.allsignsearch();
        fseObj.lettersignSearch();
        fseObj.transcriptsignSearch();
        fseObj.allnotsignSearch();
        fseObj.letternotsignSearch();
        fseObj.transcriptnotsignSearch();
        System.out.println("Document Search Test Case Completed");

    }

    /*
     * @Test(enabled=false) public void ts_2() throws FileNotFoundException,
     * BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException, RowsExceededException,
     * WriteException { System.out.println("Second TestCase---->");
     * textObj.accountNo_All(); textObj.accountNo_Letter();
     * textObj.accountNo_Transcript(); textObj.firstName_All();
     * textObj.firstName_Letter(); textObj.firstName_Transcript();
     * textObj.lastName_All(); textObj.lastName_Letter();
     * textObj.lastName_Transcript();
     * 
     * }
     */
    @Test
    public void ts_3() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
    InterruptedException, RowsExceededException, BiffException,
    WriteException {
        // webEleObj.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Third TestCase---->");
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_Today();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_Yesterday();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_ThisMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_LastMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_ThisYear();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceAll_LastYear();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_Today();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_Yesterday();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_ThisMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_LastMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_ThisYear();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceLetter_LastYear();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_Today();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_Yesterday();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_ThisMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_LastMonth();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_ThisYear();
        dateSinceObj.datesinceTranscript_LastYear();

        // logOut();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jUnit testSuite where you can define all the test classes you want to run at the same time:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MyClassTest.class, MySecondClassTest.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

You can find more info @ Vogella http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_testsuite

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code for calling any java methods in testing class:--

Class A

public class A {

```
static void method1()
{
    System.out.println("Selenium_1");
}
static void method2()
{
    System.out.println("Selenium_1");
}
```

}

Class B

public class B extends A {

```
public static void main(String ar[])
{
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

}